# Jquery Smooth Scroll only working internally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i recently asked a question and after dealing with it for like... 5 hours(unfortunately serious) i was able to smooth scroll to anchors. Here is the js i put in.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(".scroll").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     //calculate destination place
     var dest=0;
     if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
          dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
     }else{
          dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
     }
     //go to destination
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');
 });
});
```

I'm currently using ID as an anchor but i can switch to NAME too if you want.

Here's what i want: This only works within the same page. I want it to work across several pages.

Here's my example: [This page](http://hakanbaykul.com/smoothscrolltest/denemejsfiddlejump.html), should load [this page](http://hakanbaykul.com/smoothscrolltest/denemejsfiddle.html) and then scroll to the anchor.

But instead, it jumps. What should i add to this code? As a graphic and html/css only designer, javascript is rocket science to me. So i'd appreciate it if you kept it dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick to JS, and pass a hash attribute:

```
<a href="http://something.com/some.php#start"> Go to page 2 ( Start ) </a>
<a href="http://something.com/some.php#goats"> Go to page 2 ( Goats ) </a>
```

and check with a simple JS on page2

```
<script>
    $(document).one("ready",function(){
        if( window.location.hash.length > 0 ){
             $("body, html").animate({scrollTop:$(window.location.hash).position().top},1000);
        }
    });
</script>
```

The script will lead to the object having the ID "start" (or having ID "goats")
You can define the target on page2 addig an ID to Your division:

```
<div id="start"> Some content </div>
<div id="goats"> Goat content </div>
```

Comment: The problem is, i wouldn't know php if you built it as a 100 feet tall statue and shoved it up my... you know. Isn't there an html only solution?

Comment: I just updated with a JS solution, if You prefer this :)

Comment: The second solution looks too good(read: simple) to be true. Do i replace the js code on the first page with this or do i add this to the already existing js code? If the latter, Where do i add it? I know this is annoying but javascript is mind boggling for me.

Comment: The JS snippet goes to the page2, while the links I've posted go to page1. Don't forget to ID up Your elements on the 2nd page, as I've described.

Comment: My elements were already ID'd up. I've done what you said, tried removing js on the first page, tried adding your snippet to the first page, double checked my IDs, not working, it just jumps straight. I've uploaded the new code to the links in my question. Could you please check them out?

Also, my current js code doesn't properly scroll to the first anchor(junior çocuk). Since it is already visible when the page loads , guess.

Comment: My JS snippet goes to the 2nd page, as I've said before. Add the hashes to Your links on page1. If You're ID-d up on page2, You can navigate users to the anchors with this solution.

Comment: The 2nd page is where my anchor divs are, right? In this case, my 2nd page is denemefiddle.html and my first page (where my anchor links are) is denemefiddlejump.html. Sooo... i've done it but it still doesn't work. Just jumps. It works just fine within the same page.

Comment: Can You, please, provide an example, so I can help You more?

Comment: I don't wanto to post it here because it's too long. I've done what you told in these links. http://hakanbaykul.com/smoothscrolltest/denemejsfiddlejump.html my first page where the links are

and 

http://hakanbaykul.com/smoothscrolltest/denemejsfiddle.html my second page where my ID'd up anchor divs are. This where i want the links on the first page to go. It goes, but it jumps straight.

Comment: You are using a script on page1 as well, that prevents the solution from working. Delete the scripting from Your page1, where the outer links are.

Comment: I've done it hoping that it would not jump.

Well, i've deleted it, still just jumps straight.

Comment: I wrap the function for You in my JS snippet, so it won't load before the document is ready. Please, update it.

Comment: Can i kiss you? Is it legal here? 

You just saved my ass from spending another 5 hours on this "2 minutes for the expert" problem. Thank you immensely

Comment: Very nice from You. :) You can give me an upvote, if You've found my answer useful. Happy coding!